# How to delete Duplicate posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, delete-row

I have many articles which are duplicates, which means that one article is written more than one times. I have figured to find those using this MySQL command:

```
select post_title,post_content,count(*) as count from wp_posts
group by post_content
having count(*)>1
ORDER BY count(*)  DESC
```

[image]

but, How can I delete only the duplicate posts, so that if any post has more than 1 copy, then only 1 copy will be left.

Any method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I advise **backing up your SQL database** before trying the below.

Try:

```
DELETE bad_rows . * FROM ktz3_posts AS bad_rows INNER JOIN (
  SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
  FROM ktz3_posts
  GROUP BY post_title
  HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
  ) AS good_rows ON good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title
AND good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id
```

As the above code is untested, you could try the [Duplicate Post Remover](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-posts-remover/).

Comment: Hey - its been a while, but I have a question, how can I add to this query a protection to delete dupes that have the same metafiled? Eg I want SOME dupes to persist, but dupes that share a meta_value need to be erased..