# Remove duplicate posts from wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

There are posts which inserted multiple time with post_name like "icegram-2", "icegram-3", "icegram-4" along with "icegram".

Now, I want to remove posts with post_name "icegram-2", "icegram-3".

It's an example. There are more posts like this. I want to delete all such duplicate posts.

Is it possible with mysql query?

Comment: What have you tried already? This may be useful: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/help-how-to-delete-duplicate-posts-with-mysql-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following plugin:-

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/delete-duplicate-posts/

Maybe have a look at [How to delete Duplicate posts in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688492/how-to-delete-duplicate-posts-in-wordpress)

If I find anything else I will update my answer.

Comment: I tried query from [How to delete Duplicate posts in WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688492/how-to-delete-duplicate-posts-in-wordpress) but it did not work with 50000 records. It hanged.

Answer (score 0):

[Delete Duplicate Posts](https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/delete-duplicate-posts/) plugin can helpful for you